# ASP.NET Core WebApi service and Subscripion on AMPQ (Rabbit MQ)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi

The task is to make a web api (rest) service, namely, the search service.
Also this service should listen queue and reindex things on receiving an event.

What is the best way to insert listening logic to ASP.NET Core WebApi Application?

Here is working solution, but I'm not sure that is pretty good.

`Program.cs`

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();

var ampq = host.Services.GetService(typeof(IAmpqListener)) as IAmpqListener;
ampq?.Subscribe();

host.Run();
```

Comment: I don't understand how receiving a data feed has to do with ASP.NET Core in specific, this is a very broad question.

Comment: You have controller `Search` that making search. How to reindex? We can subscribe on some events and invoke some `(new Indexer).Build(newId)`

Answer (score 0):

I have a library for that on github.

This library makes simpler to listen(consume) and/or produce messages via rabbitmq.

Consumer example:

```
public class FooWorker : IWorker<FooData>
{
    public string JobName => "foo.job.name"; // Should be same as dispatched job name.

    public bool Work(FooData data)
    {
        // Lets, do whatever you want by data.

        // Return true, if working completed successfully, otherwise return false.
        return true;
    }
}
```

FooWorker is listener. Work method called when messages transferred to the queue named foo.job.name.

For more information: https://github.com/turgayozgur/tossit